# Is there a central API or language library in GCP to label all the resources?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, gcloud

To label any type of resource in GCP, the user has to use the respective APIs made for that particular resource Ex: [Compute labelling](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/labeling-resources), [Cloud SQL labelling](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/label-instance)

Is there a centralized one API or language library made available by GCP where I can label any type of resource?

There is a central [Cloud asset API](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/reference/rest) to list all resources and their information (say labels). The asset API only allows to list resources and their labels, it does not allow to label them. I am looking for a single API like the asset one to label all my resources, is there any? If there is not, is there any other best way to centrally label any type of resource other than having to use their respective individual labelling APIs?

Comment: Only the services listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-labels#label_support) support managing labels. I don't believe that this will be the right place to discuss such an issue and I strongly advise you to consider opening a [Feature Request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) on [GCP's Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list) (maybe under the Resource Manager component would be a good starting point).

Comment: Yes, I am aware that only certain services can be labelled. By asking here I just wanted to make sure that I wasn't missing anything that was already there. I will move this discussion from here to GCP Issue tracker.